# Overlapping characters in text field iText PDF

Tags: java, pdf, itext, overlapping

I have PDF with text field which contains some characters. But the language specific characters are overlapping. 
When it gains focus, text changes and displays correctly. When lost focus, displays incorrectly.
When text is edited displays also correctly.

File **test_extended_filled.pdf** see bellow

How I created PDF:

1. Created odg template in OpenOffice Draw 4.0.1 -> test.odg
2. Exported as PDF -> test.pdf
3. Edited test.pdf with Adobe Acrobat X Pro 10.0.0  and resaved with extended functions (needed to save on local PC) -> test_extended.pdf
4. **Filled form by java (pdfstamper) -> test_extended_filled.pdf**

Bonus: when i change font by pdfstamper in java it looks like changes are applied only on focused text too. -> **test_extended_filled_font_size.pdf**

Note: When I fill **test.pdf** from 2. it's displayed correctly -> **text_filled.pdf**

Attached files (go to download section):
https://rapidshare.com/share/ACC0D81E9235A6DA2CC2353BD21A4C37

After I added

```
stamper.getAcroFields().addSubstitutionFont
```

it's better, but some characters still overlap. -> **test_extended_filled_font_size_with_substitution_font.pdf**
http://rapidshare.com/share/0EE3238F37E9115C36A7A74706B09826

Any ideas?

Comment: The issue has to do with who creates the field appearances using which fonts. In addition to the files, therefore, can you post the relevant part of your font filling? That been said, I see that you are using iText 5.1.3. Please consider updating, there have been fixes concerning form filling and **NeedAppearances** support meanwhile.

Comment: See please my answers to @BrunoLowagie

Comment: I'll look at it later.

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at the [FillFormSpecialChars](http://itextpdf.com/sandbox/acroforms/FillFormSpecialChars) example and the [resulting PDF](http://itextpdf.com/sites/default/files/test.pdf).

Open Office doesn't really create nice forms. As mkl already indicates, the **NeedAppearances** flag can cause problems, the border of the fields is drawn onto the page content instead of being part of the widget annotation, etc...

In your case, you've defined a font that isn't optimal for special characters. Using a substitution font isn't ideal, because you can clearly see that drawing the glyphs isn't that much of a problem. The problem is that the metrics are all wrong. It's as if the special characters have an advance of 0 glyph units. In this case, you should change the font using the `setFieldProperty()` method.

Comment: Thank you for answer. But [resulting PDF](http://itextpdf.com/sites/default/files/test.pdf) displays incorrectly when textfield gains focus. Also you can't fill textfields neither save filled pdf to local computer.

I upgraded iText to 5.4.5.

Using **stamper.getAcroFields().setFieldProperty("test", "textfont", normalFont, null);** break PDF's extended functions.

**stamper.getAcroFields().setGenerateAppearances(true);** seems to have no effect. Result is same with or without.

Comment: I made small eclipse project called PDFFill :) which demostrates whole situation.
[PDFFill](http://rapidshare.com/share/46135B38462122BE9EAAF17B52087701)

Comment: OK, I overlooked the Reader enabling part. Reader enabling involves a digital signatures (using Adobe's private key) and meddling with those existing form fields could break that signature, even when using `PdfStamper` in append mode. Which brings me to the question: if you use Acrobat anyway to Reader-enable the document, why didn't you create the form fields using Acrobat? That would avoid all the plumbing necessary to fix the Open Office created forms...

Comment: I used Adobe LiveCycle designer and all works as expected. Open Office designer works well only with PDF without extended functions.
Thank you for help.